# String operations using different operators

Tags: java, concatenation, string-formatting, string-concatenation, type-promotion

I used this statement

```
System.out.println("Y"+90+90);
```

The answer Java shows is `Y9090`. I understand how Java does this operation. A string is concatenated with the literals if the operator `+` is used. Therefore `Y` is concatenated with 90 first, forming `Y90` as a new string and then again `Y90` is concatenated with `90` forming `Y9090` as the resultant string.

When I change the above expression to:

```
System.out.println("Y"+90-90);
```

Java shows an error. In this one, `Y` is concatenated with `90`, forming `Y90` as a new string. This new string faces with the `-` operator and produces an error.

But if i write this:

```
System.out.println("Y"+90*90);
```

It shows the answer as `Y8100`.

How can it be possible? It should have produced an error or Java should have produced a similar answer for the second statement like `Y0` without producing error.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With both pluses, the operators are evaluated left to right, so `"Y" + 90 + 90` is equal to `("Y" + 90) + 90`.

With a plus and minus, which have the same precedence, the same is true. `"Y" + 90 - 90` is equal to `("Y" + 90) - 90`. You can't subtract a number from a string, hence the compilation error.

With a plus and a multiplier, multiply has higher precedence so `"Y" + 90 * 90` is `"Y" + (90 * 90)` which compiles fine.

When in doubt, add parentheses to show your intent.

Comment: Thanks...i didn't think about that. Thought that it would have been some rules.

Comment: @JayeshSonkusare How do you mean? There are rules - very well-defined ones.